# NodeJs require('./file.js') issues

Tags: node.js, require

I am having issues including files to execute in my NodeJs project.

I have two files in the same directory:

**a.js**

```
var test = "Hello World";
```

and

**b.js**

```
require('./a.js');
console.log(test);
```

I execute b.js with `node b.js` and get the error `ReferenceError: test is not defined`.

I have looked through the docs http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

What am I missing?

Comment: FYI declaring a "var" or "let" like on a.js doesn't mean that it's accessible Globally (with require), but only inside the file a.js

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Change **a.js** to export the variable:

```
exports.test = "Hello World";
```

and assign the return value of `require('./a.js')` to a variable:

```
var a = require('./a.js');
console.log(a.test);
```

Another pattern you will often see and probably use is to assign something (an object, function) to the `module.exports` object in **a.js**, like so:

```
module.exports = { big: "string" };
```

Comment: can we still use this js file (a.js) in html ?

Comment: To be able to use it in html you should 1) code it to work as in html ; 2) export the needed functions, variables so it also work in node.

Answer (score 23):

You are misunderstanding what should be happening. The variables defined in your module are not shared. NodeJS scopes them.

You have to return it with `module.exports`.

a.js

```
module.exports = "Hello World";
```

b.js

```
var test = require('./a.js');
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to export the variable in another file.There are two patterns.
One is 
a.js
`global.test = "Hello World";` //test here is global variable,but it will  be polluted

The other is
a.js
`module.exports.test = "Hello World";` or exports.test= "Hello World";
b.js 
`var test = require('./a.js');`  //test in b.js can get the test in a.js
console.log(test);